# Error: PostgreSQL Kubernetes data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership windows

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and stuff. I was going through the tutorials, I encountered a error while using the pstgres database and persistent volume claim. I am pretty sure that all the permissions are being given to the user but still  the error suggest that the folder has wrong ownership.

Here are my configuration files

This is the persistent volume claim file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: database-persistent-volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Here is my postgres deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      component: postgres
  template: 
     metadata:
       labels:
         component: postgres
     spec:
       volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim
       containers:
         - name: postgres
           image: postgres
           ports:
             - containerPort: 5432
           volumeMounts:
             - name: postgres-storage
               mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
               subPath: postgres
           env:
             - name: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD
               value: "trust"
             - name: PGPASSWORD
               valueFrom:
                 secretKeyRef:
                   name: pgpassword
                   key: PGPASSWORD
```

```
Here is the error message 
2020-04-12 01:57:11.986 UTC [82] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
2020-04-12 01:57:11.986 UTC [82] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Did You tried to install PostgreSQL via helm https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql instead of raw manifests ?

Comment: @AlexVorona Still I did not try that way. I will give it a try.

Comment: You mention you were following a tutorial, please share the link so I can try to reproduce here!

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me check subpath in volume mount

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    metadata:
    spec:
      podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
      replicas: 1
      revisionHistoryLimit: 10
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: postgres
      serviceName: postgres
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            app: postgres
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: root
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: <Password>
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: <DB name>
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
            image: postgres:9.5
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: postgres
            ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              protocol: TCP
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-data
              subPath: pgdata
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Always
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      updateStrategy:
        rollingUpdate:
          partition: 0
        type: RollingUpdate
      volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          name: postgres-data
        spec:
          accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 3Gi
          volumeMode: Filesystem
        status:
          phase: Pending
```

Comment: I changed the subpath to pgdata but still its throwing the same error with pgdata appended  after the data.
Is it something to do with the postgres user?

Comment: Yes may possible it's due to ownership. please try adding user root and subpath as i have added.

Comment: Ok i will add the user as root and check once.

Comment: @user3184614 please let us know the result of your last test!

Comment: @willrof I am still getting the same error as initial one even after changing the user to root.

Comment: Hii, I am also facing same issue. After changing user and adding subpath also its not working for me.

Comment: delete the pvc and pv and try once again and cleanup once and try again